# error: class, interface, or enum expected JCreator

Tags: java

I have created a new class within my project called Student_Tester.java. I will use this tester class to create an instance of the Student object.
Now I am trying create an output but the following error keeps appearing:

```
error: class, interface, or enum expected
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Here is the code:

```
public class student_tester {

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Student student01 = new Student ("Tom Brown", "40030103", "1");
    }
}   
System.out.printf("%s (%s) is currently studying %s, %s and %s at Level %d", student01.getName(), student01.getNumber(), student01.getModule(1), student01.getModule(2), student01.getModule(3), student01.getLevel());
```

Comment: Well your `System.out.printf` call appears to not be in a method or even a class... where did you *want* it to be?

Comment: This has nothing to with c# right? Removed C# tag.

Comment: If you place some code outside of class, when do you think it should be invoked? Also you claim that your file is `Student_Tester.java` but your public class name is `student_tester`. That doesn't seem right since Java is case sensitive and name of public class has to be same as name of `.java` file.

Answer (score 1):

Your printf statement is defined outside of the class body. try this:

```
public class student_tester {

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Student student01 = new Student ("Tom Brown", "40030103", "1");
        System.out.printf("%s (%s) is currently studying %s, %s and %s at Level %d", student01.getName(), student01.getNumber(), student01.getModule(1), student01.getModule(2), student01.getModule(3), student01.getLevel());
    }
}
```

As a sidenote, consider naming your classes according to the [naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#15411):

> Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of
>   each internal word capitalized. Try to keep your class names simple
>   and descriptive. Use whole words-avoid acronyms and abbreviations
>   (unless the abbreviation is much more widely used than the long form,
>   such as URL or HTML).

Comment: i tried your solution and the following error occurred: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int

Comment: @NathanMcAleese It's hard without seeing the code of the Student class. Maybe ``getLevel()`` returns ``String`` rather than int?